# I have written a openMP code in C language which is solving 3D laplace equation ,but it is not showing good performance on a HPC cluster

Tags: openmp, hpc

This is the code snippet attached below.

```
        while( tol <= error )
        {
            iter = iter + 1 ;
            # pragma omp parallel shared ( error , To , T ) private ( i, j , k )
            {
            
            #pragma omp for  private ( i, j , k )
            // Updating new values  T = To
            for(i=0 ; i < ni ; i++ ){
                for(j=0 ; j < nj ; j++ ){
                    for(k=0 ;k < nk ;k++)
                        {
                            To[i][j][k] = T[i][j][k] ;
                    }   
                }
            }       
            
            error = 0.00 ;
            //Solving for mid-nodes - Central differencing
            
            #pragma omp for  private(i,j,k) reduction(max:error)
            for(i=1 ; i < ni-1 ; i++ ) {
                for(j=1 ; j < nj-1 ; j++ ){
                    for(k=1 ; k < nk-1 ;k++ ){
                        
                        T[i][j][k] = ( To[i+1][j][k] +To[i][j+1][k] +To[i][j][k+1] 
                                            + To[i-1][j][k] + To[i][j-1][k] + To[i][j][k-1] )/6;

                        //printf("T_%d%d%d = %f  from thread %d \n",i,j,k,T[i][j][k],omp_get_thread_num() );
                    error = fmax (error,fabs(T[i][j][k] - To[i][j][k]));
                }
            }
            }
        }
            printf("    %d          %lE \n",iter ,error);
            
        }
```

This is how the results look for small number of iterations on a HPC node.
[This are the results where 161s is time required when ran in serial and 180s is time required when ran in parallel i.e using #pragmas openMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19GRr.png)

This is how the array is declared and initialized

```
    double error = 1e-4 , tol = error , start , end ;
    
    printf("  ******************************\n  Variables Declared\n  ******************************\n\n");
    
    double ***T , ***To ;   
    T = (double***)malloc(ni * sizeof(double**));
    To = (double***)malloc(ni * sizeof(double**));

    for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    {
        T[i] = (double**)malloc(nj * sizeof(double*));
        To[i] = (double**)malloc(nj * sizeof(double*));
 
        for (j = 0; j < nj; j++)
        {
            T[i][j] = (double*)malloc(nk * sizeof(double));
            To[i][j] = (double*)malloc(nk * sizeof(double));
        }
    }
    

    // Initializing T
            for(i=0 ; i < ni ; i++ ){
                for(j=0 ; j < nj ; j++ ){
                    for(k=0 ;k < nk ; k++){
                    T[i][j][k] = 0.00 ;
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is mainly memory bound and so you should not expect a big speed up. 20 second per iteration seems pretty big. How big are ni, nj and nk? It would be much better if you can provide a *minimal reproducible example*. Can you provide it? Can you also specify information about the target processor(s) and OpenMP runtime parameters?

Comment: Can you also specify the compiler and compiler options used?

Comment: I have tried your code on [CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/f96afGEd5). For a smaller size array (200x200x200) OpenMP version was slower, but in the case of 1000x1000x1000 array OpenMP was ca. 3 times faster. Time=66.911578 s  (1 thread), Time=20.333166 s (8 threads) on Ryzen 7 5800X.

Comment: I think you have a race on "error"...

Comment: I'm using a GCC compiler and -fopenmp , the values of ni,nj and nk are ranging from 600*600*600 to 1000*1000*1000 . The code is showing good speed up in personal laptop but in HPC cluster the serial is performing better at every grid size . The HPC is running on intel Xeon Processors.

Comment: Ok. I guess you enabled optimizations with `-O3` and `-march=native` and possibly `-ffast-math` regarding you needs (eg. the use of NaN/Inf etc.). Beside this, 20 second per iteration seems a lot on a HPC node for such an input. How the arrays are initialized? How many cores are used? Is there multiple Xeon sockets used? Such things are very important to understand the problem.

Comment: Single node is used in HPC for running and for parallel part 4 cores are used.

Comment: Please use flatten arrays. Jagged arrays are very innefficent. "4 cores" does not means much. How are they mapped and what is the hardware topology. This was why I asked for the number of socket. To clarify this point, you can provide the result of the command `lstopo` (or `hwloc-ls`) or if this is not possible the `/proc/cpuinfo` file) in the question (and future ones related to such topic).

Comment: There are two sockets on a single node and 20Cores per socket.

Comment: Ok, so to avoid scalability issues due to [NUMA effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access), you need to pin thread to cores, parallelise the initialization using a static schedule and do the same for the computation. Flattening the arrays is also important to help memory prefetchers (in sequential and in parallel). Using two socket may be better because more memory channels could be used but additional overhead should also appear...